# my android phone is tethered to my tablet. i wanted to put games on my tablet but the games downloaded on my phone. how do i get them on my tablet

Tags: downloading

My android phone is tethered to my tablet.
I wanted to download games onto my tablet.
The games downloaded on my phone. 
How do I get them to
download to my tablet?
I used my tablet to find a game at Google play store.
When i found the game i liked 
I hit install. It said installed. Also said it would be added to my device soon. Shortly after, i got notification on my
Phone that the game was succsessfully downloaded. And was not on my tablet.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Debra! It would help if you could give us a few more details. Can you [edit] your question and explain step-by-step what you did? Then we might be able to spot the culprit and help you out.

Comment: Install Superbeam and share the app you want to from your phone to tablet and install it on receiving on your tablet..

Comment: You may try [Xender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xender&hl=en) app to share the app from Android phone to tablet or *vice versa*. However, I advise following what *Izzy* mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Shareit app from play store on both devices. Say your phone and tablet.

Now, say for example you have the game on phone and you want to sent it to your tablet.

Open Shareit on both devices and click send from your phone and click receive on your tablet. The Shareit will create a temporary hotspot to transfer files. Once it's created, search for the game from the next screen from your phone and select it and click send. If your tablet hotpot is created successfully. You will see, the name of your tablet in your phone. Tap that name and that's all. Your game will send to your tablet. After successful transfer click install.

And it's done.